# Django override __init__ form method using ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a foreign key (`zone_set`) as a choice field in a form. It should only display current project's `zone_set` . As you can see, It is not the case since it's displaying a `zone_set:`  `I belong to an other project, I should not be displayed here` which does not belong to the current project.

[image]

Here is my form but it doesn't work.

```
class ODMatrixForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ODMatrix
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('size', 'locked',)

    def __init__(self, current_project=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if current_project:
            queryset = ZoneSet.objects.filter(project=current_project)
            self.fields['zone_set'].queryset = queryset
```

The view creating the ODMatrix

```
def create_od_matrix(request, pk):
    """A roadnetwork depends on a project. It
     must be created inside the project"""
    
    current_project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ODMatrixForm(initial={'project': current_project})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request)
        od_matrix = ODMatrix(project=current_project)
        # form = ODMatrixForm(request.POST, instance=od_marix)
        form = ODMatrixForm(data=request.POST, instance=od_matrix)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "OD matrix cessfully created")
            return redirect('od_matrix_details', od_matrix.pk)

    context = {
        'project': current_project,
        'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the `__init__` as constructor of the `Meta` class, this should be a constructor of the `ODMatrixForm`, so:

```
class ODMatrixForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    #       🖟 part of ODMatrixForm, not Meta
    def __init__(self, current_project=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if current_project:
            self.fields['zone_set'].queryset = ZoneSet.objects.filter(
                project=current_project
            )
    
    class Meta:
        model = ODMatrix
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('size', 'locked',)
```

In the view, you will need to pass the `current_project` when you construct an `ODMatrixForm` object:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def create_od_matrix(request, pk):
    current_project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ODMatrixForm(current_project, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.project = current_project
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'OD matrix cessfully created')
            return redirect('od_matrix_details', od_matrix.pk)
    else:
        form = ODMatrixForm(current_project=current_project)
    context = {
        'project': current_project,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: Lot's of thanks @Willem but it is not working even after correcting the error. I added the correspondig view

Comment: It's working if I remove request.FILES. It seem it takes only two arguments? Why did you add request.FILES? As usual, your suggestions (Note) is very helpfull .

Comment: It's working now, thanks. You suggest me adding `current_project` as parameter in my `__init__` method or using `**kwargs` argument ?

Comment: @aba2s: as parameter, but perhaps better after `*args`, then you will need to rewrite the calls to the form constructor, so `ODMatrixForm(request.POST, request.FILES, current_project=current_project)`.